# Разные объекты синглетона

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть два класса: А и B. A это Sigleton, B простой класс(для примера). Так вот, разные объекты класса А никак не связаны между собой.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B {
public:
    B(int a, int b) {
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
    }
    int a, b;
};
class A {//singleton
private:
    A(){}
public:
    int x, y;
    B* b;
    static A getInstance() { 
        static A instance;
        return instance; 
    }

    bool operator==(const A& a) {
        return a.x == this->x && a.y == this->y;
    }
};

void main() {
    A* a1 = &A::getInstance();
    A* a2 = &A::getInstance();

    a1->x = 121;
    a1->b = new B(65, 12);
    cout << a2->b->a << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

В это случае `a1.x=121`, `a1.y=0`, `a1.b.a=65`, `a1.b.b=12`, а у объекта `a2` - дефолтные значения(`a2.x=0`, `a2.y=0`, `a2.b=NULL`). Что происходит?!

Comment: *A это Sigleton* и *разные обьекты класса А* - это уже нонсенс! Не может быть *несколько* объектов синглтона в одной программе!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы возвращаете *копии* объекта (кстати, закрыв конструктор по умолчанию, вы не закрыли копирующий конструктор!):

```
static A getInstance() { 
    static A instance;
    return instance; 
}
```

Нужно возвращать ссылку -

```
static A& getInstance() { 
    static A instance;
    return instance; 
}
```

Вообще непонятно, что у вас происходит и как оно компилируется:

```
A* a1 = &A::getInstance();
```

Вы получаете *указатель на временный объект*...

Comment: Спасибо вам за правки и ответ!

Comment: Ну, если ответ устраивает - помечайте как принятый.